# Storybook ignoring useEffect inside a few stories but not in others

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am using Storybook with React and writing all my stories using MDX.

I have four stories that are built every similarly, just the component is different. Inside each of the stories I have this Meta:

```
<Meta
  title="Manager/Tasks/List Card"
  component={TaskListCard}
  decorators={[
    (Story) => {
      const { state } = useTaskDialogContext();
      const isOpen = state !== false;
      return (
        <>
          <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <TasksChecklistDispatch>
              <Story />
            </TasksChecklistDispatch>
            <TaskDialog open={isOpen} />
          </DndProvider>
        </>
      );
    },
  ]}
/>
```

The `TasksChecklistDispatch` looks like this:

```js
export function TasksChecklistDispatch({ children }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log('story wrapper loaded');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('dispatching...');
    dispatch(fetchTasks());
    dispatch(fetchChecklist());
  }, [dispatch]);
  const tasks = useSelector(selectAllTasks);
  console.log(tasks);
  return children;
}
```

My issue is, that in two of those four stories, the `useEffect` part is completly ignored and not being run at all. It console logs the part before and after the useEffect, but does not run the part inside of useEffect. But it works with the other stories where I have used it.

Now I tried to run useEffect directly inside the Story itself and see what happens. I added it into the decorator of the Meta:

```
<Meta
  title="Manager/Tasks/Kanban Lane"
  component={TaskKanbanLane}
  decorators={[
    (Story) => {
      const { state } = useTaskDialogContext();
      const isOpen = state !== false;
+      useEffect(() => {
+        console.log('helloo');
+      }, [isOpen]);
      return (
        <>
          <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <TasksChecklistDispatch>
              <Story />
            </TasksChecklistDispatch>
            <TaskDialog open={isOpen} />
          </DndProvider>
        </>
      );
    },
  ]}
/>
```

And it's the same stories that don't run the useEffect, that this doesn't run either. And the same stories that *do* run it, will run this code.

I am at the end of my wits with this, does anyone has any suggestion on how to fix this issue I'm having?

Version
"@storybook/react": "^6.3.12",

EDIT: I upgraded to the latest version. It's now at 6.4.10, issue still persists.